# How to Read correctly accents characters on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, decoding, read.csv

I'm trying to read a csv file from a opendata public institution website, but when i tried to read it, it is not possible with 'utf-8' encodin; so i tried with others like 'ascii', 'ISO-8859-1' or 'latin1'. With these i'm able to read it, but it doesn't read the spanish accents ('´') and get "&oacute", for all these kind of letters. This is my code:

```py
enero2023 = pd.read_csv('/Users/leona/Documents/Presupuestos/Presupuestos C.A/Honduras/Ejecucion/202300.csv',
                         encoding='ISO-8859-1', engine='python', sep=',')
```

and i get something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAoKz.png)

as you can see, instead of get "ó" o "á", i get &""acute;

Do you know any solution to convert this substring into the actual letter with the accent?

Comment: Well, I know next to nothing about text encoding but my first instinct is to try `cp1252` because of the prevalence of Windows servers. Super easy to check. After that, I cede to every other suggestion

Comment: `import html; html.unescape('&aacute; &eacute; &Aacute;')` returns `'á é Á'`. Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share a few lines from your `csv` file (sanitized if necessary), or a link to that file.

Comment: https://www.sefin.gob.hn/download_file.php?download_file=/odata/egames/202300.csv this is the link. I paste an image with the output i get when i read the file. Basically, instead of get 'á é Á', i get '&aacute; &eacute; &Aacute;' in some of the records

Answer (score 0):

> trying to read a csv file from a opendata public institution website

Then I suggest you look into Content-Type response of headers, e.g. using requests

```
import requests
r = request.get("YOUR_DOCUMENT_URL_HERE")
print(r.headers["Content-Type"])
```

there is chance you will get charset, e.g. HTML page using UTF-8 might give `text/html; charset=UTF-8` which does mean it is `utf-8`.

If that is not possible or does not help you will need to reveal encoding using other methods, first I suggest you try using [`chardet`](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) at your file, if that fail then go through all plausible of [Standard Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

Comment: i haven't detect the encoding method, i will try one by one, but i you want to try this is the link of the file https://www.sefin.gob.hn/download_file.php?download_file=/odata/egames/202300.csv

Comment: i use chardet and i get: {'encoding': 'ISO-8859-1', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}; eventhough, i write this encoding method but i still get the problem